# Returning python script value and using that in the ansible task

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-playbook

I am new to Ansible and a bit stuck.

I have a python script that returns true or false.

I run this python script via ansible task.

I am trying to debug the value returned by running the py script.
Additionally I would want to run another task only if the value returned is true.

Ansible Task below:

```yaml
---
- name: Check XML against XSD
  become: yes
  shell: /usr/bin/python3 check.py
  args:
    chdir: "/var/www/html/det/scripts/"
  register: result
  tags: schema_check

- debug: var =schema_check.stdout
    msg: "Testing..."
    verbosity: 2
```

And the python script check.py

```py
result = true
print(result)
```

Comment: You should use exit codes like everyone else. See [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is you are registering the output as `result`, while in the `debug` task you are calling `schema_check`, which is the name of the tag.

Furthermore `debug` can only have either the `var` or the `msg` property, not both at the same time.

```yaml
- debug:
    var: result.stdout
```